# Losing scope when using array.concat() and .slice() together on jquery object list

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, concatenation, slice

I think the code will explain it, but I'm trying to slice a jquery object list into an array and then concatenate them onto another array, multiple times. Anyways in the .each function i am getting elements in the lis variable, but when I try to slice and concat them onto the listItemArray, it isn't working.  I assume I'm losing scope or there is some binding issue or something, but I can't figure out what it is.  Thanks for the help.  Also I know there is a jquery.slice method but I wanted to keep it vanilla if possible.

```
var updateSection7 = function(desired) {

    var section = $('#' + _me.UUID + ' .section7yAxis');
    var showedList = section.find('ul:not(:hidden)');
    var listItemArray = [];
    var _slice = Array.prototype.slice;


    showedList.each(function(ind,el){
        var lis = $(el).find('.control-group');
        if(lis.length>1){               
            listItemArray.concat(_slice.call(lis));             
        }
    });
}
```

UPDATED:  Here I included both the push and concat varieties of solving the problem and did away with some wasted cpu time per requests.

```
var updateSection7 = function(desired) {

    var lis = $('#' + _me.UUID + ' .section7yAxis ul:not(:hidden) .control-group');
    var listItemArray = [];
    var concatTester = [];
    var _slice = Array.prototype.slice;
    var _push = Array.prototype.push;

    //these end up doing the same thing 
    _push.apply(listItemArray, _slice.call(lis));
    concatTester = concatTester.concat(_slice.call(lis));
}
```

Comment: Not sure I get it? Wouldn't `$('#' + _me.UUID + ' .section7yAxis ul:not(:hidden) .control-group')` do the same ?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? The code shown is nothing more than wasted cpu time :)

Comment: `.concat()` doesn't mutate the original array. Use `.push()` like this: `var _push = Array.prototype.push;` `_push.apply(listItemArray, _slice.call(lis));` You won't need the `_slice()` here if you don't need to support older browsers.

Comment: @adeneo I don't think it would do the same because there are going to be multiple ul's, I could be wrong though.

Comment: @Andreas are you saying that because of the heavy dom traversal/jquery?

Comment: @adeneo: OP is only adding `.control-group` items when there's more than `1` found under a given `ul:not(:hidden)`. If this was a mistake, and all should be added, then your way is definitely better.

Comment: You're trying to save `.control-group` items in a local array but then you're not using them for anything else.

Comment: @cookiemonster - or just add `:gt(1)` at the end of my selector ?

Comment: @adeneo: Won't that take the entire result set into account instead of each individual collection under each `ul`?

Comment: @adeneo: check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/mXhTL/ The result is odd. It seems that the `:gt(1)` is applied to the `ul` instead of the `.control-group`. Can you make sense of that? Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: @cookiemonster - Probably, another option would be `:not(:first-child)`

Comment: thanks for the insights all.  I'd like to note that @cookiemonster had a correct answer along with friedi.

Comment: @adeneo: Perhaps, if the `.control-group` class is applied to all children. Not sure. Still the `:gt()` result was weird.

Comment: @cookiemonster - http://jsfiddle.net/mXhTL/2/

Comment: I haven't full tested, but I'm pretty sure that the conditionals were me being bogged down in an implementation detail that's already taken care of.  Anywho, I updated.

Comment: @adeneo: Yeah, I thought about `:has()`, but couldn't bring myself to suggest it because it'll be doing a double DOM selection under the `ul` elements.

Comment: @cookiemonster - It will, but it still looks better than all the array stuff, depending on what the array in the question is supposed to be used for ?

Comment: Now with the changes in the question, it makes even less sense ?

Comment: @adeneo: True. Here's a version that works if not all children have the `.control-group` class. It uses `.nth-of-type` instead. http://jsfiddle.net/mXhTL/5/

Comment: ...yeah, not sure what OP is after now. I think he's ultimately using your solution.

Comment: Hahaha I was just testing both varieties.  My issue was that I was using concat and not re assigning the concat to the listItemArray.  I didn't post all of the code that goes with it.  Later on I need to access different parts of the stuff bound to section.  That's why the jquery was pieced up.   All i really cared about was      _push.apply(listItemArray, _slice.call(lis));
    concatTester = concatTester.concat(_slice.call(lis));

Comment: Bradgnar: Sorry for hijacking your question for this discussion. :) @adeneo: I see my original confusion about the result from `:gt()` was that I forgot that it was `0` based, so it appeared to be operating on the parent. This demo cleared it up for me. http://jsfiddle.net/mXhTL/6/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`concat` doesn't mutate the original array. It returns the new array.

Try this:

```
listItemArray = listItemArray.concat(_slice.call(lis));
```